# Set ARITHABORT On only fail in asp

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, asp-classic, arithabort

I have this error message :

```
SELECT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ARITHABORT'.
Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed
columns and/or query notifications and/or xml data type methods.
```

I only want to know why it's giving me the error when i'm calling my stored proc from the asp code and it give me no error when i'm in management studio ?

I know it's because i use some xml data in my stored proc but what's the difference between management studio and the code

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Management Studio sets these options for you, and they are not the same defaults that are applied when connecting through SQLNCLI etc. Take a look at Tools > Options > Query Execution > SQL Server > Advanced and you will see that you can set various settings for ARITHABORT etc.

Also I don't think it's because you are using XML, I think it's because your stored procedure either explicitly sets arithabort or it was created with the opposite setting.

Comment: It was not explicitly set And for the creation what do you mean ? If i'm creating my procedure and thant executing it withouth changing the options should the arithabort be the same at the creation and the execution